# Combine two different table cell ratios in data validation

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, excel-2010

What I want is to make a list menu from different ratios of table cells combining them into one list.

There is a title in center of the two list types and I don't want to include that in the data validation list.

For example I cannot use a data validation list like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDyes.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is impossible to do that. What you could do is copy the values you want (so leave the title out) in your data validation (eg. to a different worksheet) and select those values.

At least that is what someone suggested on this matter.
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/43365-data-validation-list.html

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I don't really know how to put together that function. Any help would still be very appreciated.

Comment: You could copy the values you want manually or do something with VBA. Unfortunately  I am not experienced enough to give you any tips on that. This might help though: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Data-Validation-list-from-0b13f05c#content